# ComponentHierarchyIterator alternative in Apache Wicket 9.2 version

Tags: java, wicket

I got stuck while doing migration of Apache Wicket 7.9 to 9.2 version.

In 7.9 version, there is `visitChildren` ([link](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/45ee588034e14a152b370cb5545a3e488c7213a0/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/MarkupContainer.java#L1006)) method which returns `ComponentHierarchyIterator` ([link](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/45ee588034e14a152b370cb5545a3e488c7213a0/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/util/iterator/ComponentHierarchyIterator.java#L38)) based on clazz parameter. Both `ComponentHierarchyIterator` and the `visitChildren` method are deprecated in 7.9 and removed in latest versions.

The documentation says to use `Use {@link org.apache.wicket.util.visit.IVisitor} instead` of `ComponentHierarchyIterator`. However, `IVisitor` is an interface and I was not able to find an implementation of visitor which returns all the components hierarchy or fulfils the requirement.

There is one `DeepChildFirstVisitor` abstract class which is an implementation of `IVisitor` which I'm trying to use.

My 7.9 version codebase is :

```
       for (Component m : pushMenuContainer.visitChildren(PushMenu.class)) {
            if (!menu.equals(m)) {
                ((PushMenu) m).hide();
            }
        }
```

My 9.2 codebase after migration will be something like

```
       for (Component m : pushMenuContainer.visitChildren(PushMenu.class, new IVisitorUnknownImplementation())) {
            if (!menu.equals(m)) {
                ((PushMenu) m).hide();
            }
        }
```

I need guidance as to which visitor I should use, if it's available in Apache Wicket 9.2 as an alternative to ComponentHierarchyIterator?

Also, if there is none available, then does it mean that I have to implement my own Hierarchy visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous implementation of IVisitor:

```
pushMenuContainer.visitChildren(PushMenu.class, new IVisitor<PushMenu, Void>() {
      @Override public void component(PushMenu pushMenu, IVisit<Void> visit) {
          if (!menu.equals(pushMenu)) {
              pushMenu.hide();
          }
      }
});
```

Comment: Looks like the definition has changed in 9.2, now it requires to override component method instead of visit `@Override public void component(Object object, IVisit visit) {    }`

Comment: My mistake. Fixed it!

Comment: We also need to define `IVisitor` with a type otherwise it'll have `component(Object obj, IVisit<Object> visit)`. Therefore the IVisitor will be like `new IVisitor<Component, Object>() {`